# How to Display "No Items Were Found" React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React.js App where I search pets as below
[image]

When the page first loads, I display some text and image. Then user makes a search and gets the results according to the search. But if there is no matching results, I want to display a message as "No Items were found"
How can I do this ?
My if condition is not working in the submit function.

Below is my code

```
Search.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SearchResults from "./SearchResults";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FaSearch } from "react-icons/fa";
import "./Search.css";
import { useFormik } from 'formik';

const Search = ({ searchGuests }) => {

  const [searchResults, setSearchresults] = React.useState([])

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      location: "",
      age: "",
      breed: "",
      gender: "",
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      const searchItem = searchGuests.guestsResults.filter(item => {
        return (
          item.location
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(
              values.location.toLowerCase()
            ) &&
          item.age
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(
              values.age.toLowerCase()
            ) &&
          item.breed
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(
              values.breed.toLowerCase()
            ) &&
          item.gender
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(
              values.gender.toLowerCase()
            )
        )
      })
      if(searchItem) {
        return setSearchresults(searchItem)
      } else {
        return searchResults("No Items Were Found")
      }
      // return JSON.stringify(values, null, 2);
    },
  });

  const LoadingPage = () => {
    return (
      <Col sm={12} className="loadPage">
        <h4>Start Searching Now and Discover New Friends</h4>
        <h6>They are waiting for their new home</h6>
        <img src="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/67586673.cms" className="w-100 searchCatLogo" />
      </Col>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row className="searchContainer py-5">
        <h1>{searchGuests.searchGuestsTitle.title}</h1>
        <Col sm={12}>
          <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} className="searchForm">
            <label htmlFor="location"></label>
            <select id="location" name="location" value={formik.values.location} {...formik.getFieldProps('location')}>
              <option value="Select Location">Select Location</option>
              {searchGuests.locationCities.map(city => <option>{city}</option>)}
            </select>

            <label htmlFor="age"></label>
            <input
              id="age"
              type="text"
              placeholder="age"
              {...formik.getFieldProps('age')}
            />

            <label htmlFor="breed"></label>
            <select id="breed" name="breed" value={formik.values.breed} {...formik.getFieldProps('breed')}>
              <option value="Select Breed">Select Breed</option>
              {searchGuests.searchBreed.map(breed => <option>{breed}</option>)}
            </select>

            <label htmlFor="gender"></label>
            <select name="gender" value={formik.values.gender} {...formik.getFieldProps('gender')}>
              <option value="Select Gender">Select Gender</option>
              <option value="Female">Female</option>
              <option value="Male">Male</option>
            </select>

            <button type="submit">
              <FaSearch size={27} className="searchIcon" />
            </button>
          </form>
        </Col>
        <Col sm={12}>
          <Row className="mt-5 items">
            {searchResults.length > 0 ? searchResults.map(result => {
              return (
                <SearchResults
                  key={result.id}
                  img={result.img}
                  location={result.location}
                  age={result.age}
                  breed={result.breed}
                  gender={result.gender}
                  name={result.name}
                />
              )
            }) : <LoadingPage />}
          </Row>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

```
SearchResults.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Col, Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./Search.css";
import { BsGeoAlt } from "react-icons/bs";
import { FaPaw } from "react-icons/fa";
import AdoptionFormModal from "./AdoptionFormModal"


const SearchResults = ({ img, id, location, age, breed, gender, name }) => {

  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <Col lg={4} className="mb-5">
                <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={img} />
                    <Card.Body id="modalBody">
                        <Card.Text id="cardText">
                            <div className="firstDiv">
                                <p>{breed}</p>
                                <p>{name}</p>
                                <Button variant="primary" className="adoptButton shadow-none" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>
                                    <FaPaw className="pawIcon"/>
                                    Adopt
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="secondDiv">
                                <p>{gender}, {age}</p>
                                <p className="mt-4"><BsGeoAlt size={25}/> {location}</p>
                            </div>
                        </Card.Text>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </Col>
            <AdoptionFormModal
              show={modalShow}
              onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default SearchResults;
```

```
data.js
export let searchGuests = {
    searchGuestsTitle: {
      title: "Adopt Your New Pet",
    },
    guestsResults: [
      {
        id: 1,
        img:
          "https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F37%2F2020%2F09%2F22%2F50-cute-dog-names.jpg",
        location: "Istanbul",
        age: "2",
        breed: "Poodle",
        gender: "Female",
        name: "Sushi",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        img:
          "https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F37%2F2020%2F09%2F22%2F50-cute-dog-names.jpg",
        location: "Istanbul",
        age: "1",
        breed: "Terrier",
        gender: "Male",
        name: "Sushi",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        img:
          "https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F37%2F2020%2F09%2F22%2F50-cute-dog-names.jpg",
        location: "Istanbul",
        age: "2",
        breed: "Poodle",
        gender: "Female",
        name: "Sushi",
      },
    ],
    locationCities : [
      "Istanbul",
      "Ankara",
      "Izmir"
    ],
    searchBreed : [
      "Poodle",
      "Terrier",
      "Rottweiler",
      "Golden Retriever",
      "Cat",
      "Tobby cat",
      "Scottish"
    ],
    searchAge : [
      "<3",
      ">3",
      "All"
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can render it based on the type of `searchResults` is a string or array

```
  {/* Show result */}
  {searchResults.length > 0 &&
    Array.isArray(searchResults) &&
    searchResults.map((result) => {
      return (
        <SearchResults
          key={result.id}
          img={result.img}
          location={result.location}
          age={result.age}
          breed={result.breed}
          gender={result.gender}
          name={result.name}
        />
      );
    })}

  {/* Show  notfound */}

  {searchResults.length > 0 && typeof searchResults === "string" && (
    <div>{searchResults}</div>
  )}

  {/* Show  loading */}
  {searchResults.length === 0 && <LoadingPage />}

  if(searchItem.length > 0) {
    return setSearchresults(searchItem)
  } else {
    return searchResults("No Items Were Found")
  }
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, seach functionality does not work with this :(

Comment: I put the whole code but search functionality does not work :/

Comment: I did try this as well. but this time it brings LoadingPage when there is no match :(

Comment: I really really thank you for your help, I appreciate it. I tried this but the problem is I m not able to write if condition in react render part. I used ternary operator but since searchItem is in a local scope in a JS function, it cannot reach from there. I tried this condition in the submit function, but then cannot read searchItem.length since the map is not in the function itself. I really dont know where i make the mistake and the logic here. I just wanted to make a loading page when user loads the page and make a search and them get an error when there is no match

Answer (score 0):

**First: You are directly mutated the state, so your component won't re-render:**

```
return searchResults("No Items Were Found")
```

And also it's inefficient to save error state the same state you store your  response, so create another state for that:

```
const [error, setError] = React.useState('')
```

And then set your error like this:

```
setError("No Items Were Found")
return;
```

**Lastly, check for the existent of error and render it:**

```
{error && <p>{error}</p>
```

Comment: I made like this in the submit function but when there is no match it brings the LoadingPage which I see when the page first load because i made a condition for that to show that page if the results.length > 0 
if(searchItem) {
return setSearchresults(searchItem)
} else {
 setError("No Items Were Found");
return error && <p>{error}</p>
} 
this also did not work :(

Comment: Put your `error && <p>{error}</p> ` before `searchResults.length > 0 `

Comment: sure, i did like this but still gives me the LoadingPage when there is no match 
            {error && <p>{error}</p> } 
            {searchResults.length > 0 ? searchResults.map(result => {
              return (
                <SearchResults
                  key={result.id}
                  img={result.img}
                  location={result.location}
                  age={result.age}
                  breed={result.breed}
                  gender={result.gender}
                  name={result.name}
                />
              )
            }) : <LoadingPage />}